# live in not working in jquery-1.9.1.min.js

Tags: live

I have following  code in my **JS** file

```
$("a#confirm_roommate").live('click',function(){
    //code
});
```

But is doesn't work in *jquery-1.9.1.min.js*. It gives error that live is not function..

Anything wrong..?

Comment: post your errors from the console

Answer (score 2):

from [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().
```

it was also **removed** from 1.9

so you should use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Here is the solution that i have find $(document).on('click','a#confirm_roommate',function(){ //code is here });  its working fine now

Comment: If this solves your question, you should accept the answer :)

Comment: @NDM My impression is that people with very low reputation who ask questions are less likely to accept answers, maybe because they are not very familiar with the Stackoverflow system and they just leave for good. But it is definitely good manners to accept the answer that helps or resolves your problem/question. The asker's reputation was 11.

Comment: I know http://api.jquery.com/live/ says this about .live( events, handler ): "version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9". Does "1.9" means only 1.9, excluding "1.9.x"? I guess so.

Comment: it means it is removed in 1.9.0 and up